# Is JDBC Connection aquiring with MySQL slower than with Derby, for example?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ehcache, derby, c3p0

I use

- Tomcat
- C3p0 (JNDI configured inside Tomcat)
- MySQL (InnoDB) / Derby (not embedded) as Database
- EHCache (in Memory)
- Hibernate
- Testmachine runs WinXP

I used Derby for development and wanted to switch to MySQL. I was surprised to see that with MySQL my Tests were approximately 50% slower than with Derby.

My Testscenario :

- Approximately 2000 Selects, varying in complexity, but none used more than one join. All SQLs use Indexes
- Ehcache is filled up with a setup Run. After that I run the Testscenario at least 50x to overcome Optimizer/GC Effects

I verified that the cache is in use. There are NO real SQLs coming to the database. So I just guess it's the connection creation time which slows the MySQL tests down.

Comment: If you're using C3P0, wouldn't the connections be pooled/cached?

Comment: yes that should be the case, hmm maybe c3p0 makes some tests before it returns the connection from the pool. ill look into that

Comment: In my experience, establishing connections to MySQL has always been very fast.  Have you tried using a profiler?

Comment: I don't have the same settings as you, but i've always found MySQL to be quite fast about JDBC connections. I'm running DBCP as the pool connection, MySQL (InnoDB) / Oracle / HSQLDB, Linux or Solaris OS, and in the end, the winner is HSQLDB, closely followed by MySQL. Maybe you should check the new pool created by the Tomcat folks : http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: If there are no SQL statements being executed due to the caching, why would there be any connections?

Comment: Derby is filebased database